# Injected Mock behavior not used in constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Using Mockito **annotations** (`MockitoJUnitRunner.class`, `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TagRepositoryTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TagRepository repository;

    @Mock
    private SetupDetails setupDetails;

    ....
}
```

I have the **test target class** using the injected dependency in the constructor:

```
public class TagRepository {

    private final Collection<Tag> tags;

    @Autowired
    public TagRepository(SetupDetails setupDetails) {
        this.tags = Arrays.asList(
                new Tag("name", setupDetails.getSourceId()),
                ...
        );
    ...
}
```

And I am currently **stubbing** the method call in `@Setup` or inside `@Test` with `when()`:

```
when(setupDetails.getSourceId()).thenReturn("1");
```

This is **not working** as expected. Mockito seems to only stub the method call after the `@InjectMocks TagRepository` constructor is called, resulting in a `null` beeing returned instead of `"1"`.

**Is there a way to get the stub ready before the constructor is called (using Mockito annotations)?**

Comment: what is it that you're trying to accomplish using annotations? `when(setupDetails.getSourceId()).thenReturn("1");`? no, there is no way to accomplish that with annotations. However, you can still use `@Mock` etc without issues.

Comment: I just edited the question (hopefully) to clarify what is not working and what do I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I am being able to work around this is trying to control the order Mockito setups this scenario giving up on Mockito annotations:

```
public void setUp() {
    setupDetails = mock(SetupDetails.class);
    when(setupDetails.getDbId()).thenReturn("1");

    repository = new TagRepository(setupDetails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed this is the case and your "work around" is the way to go.
Some will argue that this is a good practice as your test will not compile when you introduce more members to your class under test, as you'll also add them to the constructor.

Comment: You mean more dependencies passed on the constructor? Also, maybe your comment could be a comment to the "work around" answer?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Regarding commenting on the work around answer... well, I'm a new user and can't comment yet on other's answers :)